# Get Secret Hats in winter bash 2015

Tags: discussion, bug, winter-bash-2015

How do I get secret hats in winter bash 2015? I wonder if I could wear as many as hats I get

Comment: What the heck is "Winter Base"?

Comment: @Braiam http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [The first rule of secret hats is: You do not talk about secret hats. The second rule of secret hats is...](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fight_Club_%28film%29#Tyler_Durden)

Comment: Why so many downvotes ?

Comment: because... hmm... hmmmmm... secret?

Comment: Yeah, and `bug` tag is very accurate here ;)

Answer (score 16):

You have to figure it out. Or if you really don't want to, some people will [spill the beans about secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) as they figure out what triggers them.

Comment: see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271155/winter-bash-2015-people-crazy-about-hats